# Bluetooth doesn't work on my mobile phone

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey, android-bluetooth, c++builder-xe7

I can transfer some Embarcadero  builder xe7  examples to my  xperia si18  phone with 4.0.4  android version ( api 15 ). Tethering, LOcationDemo, webbrowser ...  works well  BUT all of the Bluetooth examples doesn't worK. I have tried to select some different "SDK bluetooth permission" on the IDE option, switch on bluetooth on my phone .BUT 
a black screen appears or just the firemonkey icon when i launch the application   . if i use a  new project with a simple button and just add  as header : #include   and develop on my device, the problem is the same !!!

do i have to do something special to be able to run a bluetooth application on my mobil phone 
Thank for help...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Check the actual XML that gets deployed. I know for Xe5 or Xe6 ( dont remember ) you had manually edit the deployment file after building & before deploying for internet permission

Comment: sorry  . if i use a new project with a simple button and just add as header : #include <System.Bluetooth.hpp>   the problem is the same !!!  BLACK SCREEN OR FIREMONKEY ICON

Comment: here are a part of the AndroidManifest.  Bluetooth seems to be OK   :   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />